# npm scripts hang indefinitely on Concourse CI

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, concourse

On Concourse, I am running integration tests where I run certain npm scripts. There is a particular script that build my backend/frontend and then proceeds to run the tests. However once the test is done (fail or succeed). the npm script does not stop. It doesn't error out and hangs indefinitely either when the tests fail or succeeds. I have run this script on a local machine and a local container and the npm script works fine. Only on Concourse, the script hangs forever.

To give more context to my setup here is a sample of the npm script which is run on the frontend

```
"ci:start:backend": "npm run --prefix ../emailservice/mock-service dev & npm run --prefix ../server-repo ci:start:server & sleep 3"

"ci:test:system": "npm run ci:start:backend && npm run build:dist:serve & sleep 90 && npm run test:browser:ci"
```

`npm run ci:test:system` is the main script that is run. What it does it will start running an email service, a server and the frontend all at once in order to run the tests. It is a messy way of doing things but it works for both local and in containers. This method has been done for similar tests for server testing and it is running on concourse fine.

The task of the pipeline can be seen below

```
# runs unit tests for frontend
  - name: run-tests
    plan:
    - get: frontend-repo
    - get: server-repo
    - get: emailservice
    - task: run-npm-tests
      privileged: true
      config:
        platform: linux
        image_resource:
          type: docker-image
          source:
            repository: jonoc/techradar-integration
        inputs:
          - name: frontend-repo
          - name: server-repo
          - name: emailservice
        run:
          path: sh
          args:
          - -exc
          - |
            mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
            export SHELL=/bin/bash

            cd server-repo
            npm install --silent

            cd ../emailservice/mock-service
            npm install --silent

            cd ../../frontend-repo
            npm install --silent

            npm rebuild node-sass --silent
            npm run postinstall --silent
            npm run ci:test:system
```

Everything seems to be not out of the ordinary but concourse refuses to give a green or red build. I suspect it is due to the other scripts that are run forever but are hanging in the background and concourse does not want to end. However running npm run ci:start:backend in concourse will work fine, but running npm run test:browser:ci will hang forever which further adds confusion to whats the problem.

Concourse version:3.3.2

Deployment type (BOSH/Docker/binary):Docker

Infrastructure/IaaS:AWS/EC2

Browser (if applicable):Chrome

Did this used to work? Never

Comment: Have you tried killing the pids started once your tests finish?

If you add an echo line below the `npm run ci:test:system`, do you see the output?

Comment: Yeah so I added a line below `npm run ci:test:system` and it is never run because the script about does not end. Since that script runs the tests, I am not sure how I can kill the pids during the duration of the test

Comment: Are you running PhantomJS perchance?

Comment: No we are running protractor and headless chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is resolved by changing up my npm scripts. Turns out chaining `npm run --prefix ../emailservice/mock-service dev & npm run --prefix ../server-repo ci:start:server & sleep 3` with the other scripts causes some issues on Concourse.

I modified the npm scripts to use `npm-run-all` and use the `-r` parameter to finish the script when my tests are done

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your resources are available in the tasks docker container?

You specify multiple inputs here

```
 - name: frontend-repo
 - name: server-repo
 - name: emailservice
```

But concourse requires you to specify a proper path for each input if you have more than one.

Try to hijack the task container after execution and check if the resources are available. You can also execute the script in the container, so you can debug it easier.

`fly -t <your_target> hijack -j demo_job/demo_task`

Comment: The resources are available in the container as the I can cd into each input and run the npm scripts